Generate new motions for Nao in webots using Choregraphe behaviors
Webots has some limited predefined motions for Nao robot. On the other hand, Choregraphe also has some predefined behaviors for Nao.
The motions in webots are .txt files in which you can see the related joints and their values in different time steps. However, Choregraphe's predefined behaviors are box.xar files (I could not extract them).
Now my question is, is it possible to somehow convert the Choregraphe behaviors to Webots motions?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
